# CSS Custom RadioButton not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm making a simple custom radio button using CSS and I don't know why is not working as like a normal radio button. When I choose one, the other selected itself too (?).

```css
/* Radio Button */

.radioBtn{
   float: right;
   margin-top: 30px;
   height: 35px;
   width: 35px;
   border: solid 3px #d8aa00;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #fffbd8;
   position: relative;
   transition: .3s;
}


.radioBtn::after{
   position: absolute;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background: #d8aa00;
   border-radius: 50%;
   content: '';
   top: 7px;
   left: 7px;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: .3s;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .radioBtn::after {
   opacity: 1;
 }

 input[type=radio]{
    display: none;
 }
```

```html
<input id="radioBtn" type="radio" name="test">
<label class="radioBtn" for="radioBtn"></label>

<input id="radioBtn2" type="radio" name="test">
<label class="radioBtn" for="radioBtn2"></label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `~` to target **only** the immediate sibling placed after and not **all** of them.

> The + combinator selects **adjacent siblings**. This means that **the second**
>   **element directly follows the first**, and both share the same parent.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators)</sup>

---

> The ~ combinator selects siblings. This means that **the second element**
>   **follows the first** **(though not necessarily immediately)**, and both share
>   the same parent<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators)</sup>

```css
/* Radio Button */

.radioBtn{
   float: right;
   margin-top: 30px;
   height: 35px;
   width: 35px;
   border: solid 3px #d8aa00;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #fffbd8;
   position: relative;
   transition: .3s;
}


.radioBtn::after{
   position: absolute;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background: #d8aa00;
   border-radius: 50%;
   content: '';
   top: 7px;
   left: 7px;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: .3s;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .radioBtn::after {
   opacity: 1;
 }

 input[type=radio]{
    display: none;
 }
```

```html
<input id="radioBtn" type="radio" name="test">
<label class="radioBtn" for="radioBtn"></label>

<input id="radioBtn2" type="radio" name="test">
<label class="radioBtn" for="radioBtn2"></label>
```

Comment: Probably helpful to explain the actual difference between the sibling selectors `+` and `~` in a little detail.

Comment: @j08691 added ;)

Comment: Wooooww!! Thanks a lot man! you are my hero (: !! Very clear explaination!